# Forcing optimalisation selectively on a std operator overloads

Tags: c++

For code I own, I can selectively force a lot of things with `__attribute__` which is amazing. However, I would like to selectively change a function I do not have access to. I tried to put it into a wrapper like this, naively hoping it would 'inherit' it and do what I want (of course it did not as the code is compiled in a different order than it's called):

```cpp
std::atomic_int32_t safeValue;

__attribute((optimize("-O3"),always_inline))
inline void setAtomic()  {
    safeValue = 10;
}
```

When compiled with -O0 it still resulted in a jump to a generic implementation with a lot of overhead. In my target platform (RISC-V) there are atomic instructions and they are pretty fast. Just I would like to debug my application when I do a -O0 build, but not having to waste performance on each atomic operation, as I will be debugging the application itself and not if the atomic operations got implemented correctly in the toolchain.

The overhead is not small:
https://godbolt.org/z/aqWKrbT8v

While when I enabled -O1 it got so much better:
https://godbolt.org/z/naf7Y6dqo

Just I would like to be my O0 build to be close to the O1 when I do the atomic functions. I know what I'm asking is very odd, but C++ has features like *friend* so the idea to affect stuff that is out of our control/scope is not completely alien to the standard. In this case, I want to tweak how the operand= overload is optimized without having access to the code.

I tried in a desperate attempt to push the settings and then pop them: https://godbolt.org/z/qajWos6v7

But that of course didn't work (because the things are not compiled in the same order as they are called)

So I wonder if there is some solution to this at all, or some dirty (but not too extreme) workaround, or the answer is plain NO. Technically speaking I have access to the STD and I could change it there and in the past I recompiled the toolchain with various gcc/gdb tweaks, but it doesn't feel right.

One idea I did not try is to have child atomic implementation, which would inherit the atomic, and override the operator overloads with my functions. Not sure if this might be a way to do it, or am I thinking in a completely wrong direction.

In the meantime, my solution is to have its own implementation of atomic functions where my C functions (not even C++) are inlined with the handcrafted assembly (together with correct clobbers https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html it works very well). Just it doesn't feel right to reimplement functionality when std has something built-in already, just I do not have as much control to tweak it as I wanted.

Comment: Part of your conceptual problem might be that `friend` is a C++ language feature, but optimization is very much a compiler feature. Those are very different domains.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, the __attribute__ is gcc feature and not the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that the relevant definitions are in the `#include <atomic>`. You would need to put that at the top of your source file, surrounded by

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O3")
#include <atomic>
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html)

Of course, this is not at all "selective", as your title requests, but it's easily tested and more likely to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://godbolt.org/z/rbaqTfnEb Doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: @AntonKrug: Sorry, I don't understand enough what that example is trying to convey. The idea seems right, but I realize you might want a pragma push/pop before /after

Comment: change the gcc argument in the example to O1 and you will see how much more optimized it is, not doing calls to a generic implementation and inlining directly amoswap without any bloat.

Comment: Actually, it does the optimizations (except the inlining, which is ok as the application is O0 anyway). And it's doing a jump, not to a generic implementation, but optimised one, when changed the filtering it shows pretty well: https://godbolt.org/z/s69Wd1n8P Yes it's not as selective and does it fully on whole atomic and it's dependencies, but that's ok. Thankyou very much